# Irreducibility of a polynomial in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

The question asks me to show that $\mathbb{Z}_{13}[x]/\langle x^{2014}-x^{1000}+1 \rangle$ is a field.

Now what I know is that since $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ is a field, so if I show that $x^{2014}-x^{1000}+1 $ is irreducible, then $\langle x^{2014}-x^{1000}+1 \rangle$ will be a maximal ideal and so $\mathbb{Z}_{13}[x]/\langle x^{2014}-x^{1000}+1 \rangle$ will be a field.

But I don't see how to show the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}[x]$. For the degree $\le 3$, I could use whether there is a root or not but I don't know for such a big degree.

Maybe there is a duplicate for this question, but please help anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true.  The polynomial $x^{2014}-x^{1000}+1$ has $x^2+6$ as a factor, and in particular is not irreducible.  You can quickly verify this by observing that if $x^2=-6$ then (working in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$) $$x^{2014}-x^{1000}+1=(-6)^{1007}-(-6)^{500}+1=(-6)^{11}-(-6)^8+1=0.$$

Comment: is there a sure shot method to find irreducibility in an arbitrary $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ or we have to find some factor as you did. How to come up with such a factor?

Comment: I found it with a computer.  For algorithms for factoring polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that before I asked the question, but thought there might be some general method like reduction etc which I couldn't find. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In this particular case, you could do it by noticing that even though $x^{2014}-x^{1000}+1$ does not have a root in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$, $y^{1007}-y^{500}+1$ does, and so this gives a quadratic factor.  If there weren't a quadratic factor, though, I don't think there would have been any shortcut.

Answer (score -2):

**HINT**

Use the fact that for $p=13$ prime, $x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.  The resulting t3nth degree polynomial is much easier to work with.

Comment: This works for elements, not for polynomials: $1$ and $x^{12}$ are *different* polynomials even though they induce the same *function*.

Comment: @Mark Fischler I know what you wrote is Fermat's theorem but how to use it here?

Comment: There’s really no way to use Little Fermat in a case like this, far as I know.